# Kernels not running concurrently in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I have a kernel that runs on my GPU (GeForce 690) and uses a single block.  It runs in about `160` microseconds.  My plan is to launch `8` of these kernels separately, each of which only uses a single block, so each would run on a separate SM, and then they'd all run concurrently, hopefully in about `160` microseconds.

However, when I do that, the total time increases linearly with each kernel: `320` microseconds if I run `2` kernels, about `490` microseconds for `3` kernels, etc.

My question: Do I need to set any flag somewhere to get these kernels to run concurrently?  Or do I have to do something that isn't obvious?

Comment: Are you using streams? Maybe I'm wrong, but if you just run `8` kernels separately they will be executed in sequence within the default stream. Have a look at the `concurrentKernels` SDK example provided with the CUDA installation.

Comment: What @JackOLantern said may very well be true: if you do not define the stream for each kernel, the same stream is going to do everything, sequentially. Hence, you need to explicitly define 8 `cudaStream_t`s. I have nearly the same graphics card on which this does work, so that is probably what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @JackOLantern indicated concurrent kernels require the usage of streams, which are required for [all forms of asynchronous activity scheduling](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#asynchronous-concurrent-execution) on the GPU. It also requires a GPU of compute capability 2.0 or greater, generally speaking.  If you do not use streams in your application, all cuda API and kernel calls will be executed sequentially, in the order in which they were issued in the code, with no overlap from one call/kernel to the next.

Rather than give a complete tutorial here, please review the [concurrent kernels cuda sample](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#concurrent-kernels) that JackOlantern referenced.

Also note that actually witnessing concurrent execution can be more difficult on windows, for a variety of reasons.  If you run the concurrent kernels sample, it will indicate pretty quickly if the environment you are in (OS, driver, etc.) is providing concurrent execution.